# samsung smart tv upload file

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

On the samsung dforum I found the [URL](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/ref00011/deviceapi_download_onuploadprogress.html) which explains a function `startUpload()`.

but also in forums i found people saying that uploading files by any means is not possible. If so why samsung provide the `startUpload()` function?

Did anybody tried file upload? please help

Comment: is there link for forum thread?

Comment: Ivan, you can find this on samsungdforum.com easily

Comment: [this thread](http://www.samsungdforum.com/SamsungDForum/ForumView/a56519250d733296?forumID=eb25ba9af878e288) suggest that upload is partially working

Comment: I don't think so. A user is claiming to have uploaded files. Is it believable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation is incorrect. I tested it on UE46ES8000 and successfully uploaded file from USB flash drive connected to TV.
`OnComplete` callback called instead of `OnUploadComplete`.

To the end of uploaded data appended string `--END_OF_PART--`. If you strip it from file, you get your original file.

```
function OnUploadComplete (msg) {
    alert('***OnUploadComplete***' + msg );
}
function OnUploadProgress (msg) {
    alert('***OnUploadProgress***' + msg );
}

function fnDnStatus (msg) {
    alert('fnCallback' + msg );
    var tArrResult = msg.split("?");
    for (var i=0; i < tArrResult.length; i++) {
        alert("tArrResult[" + i + "] = " + tArrResult[i]);
    }
    // DownResult: If res=1 success, otherwise ERROR (see end of this file)
}

var DownloadPlugin = document.getElementById("pluginObjectDownload");
DownloadPlugin.OnUploadComplete = OnUploadComplete;
DownloadPlugin.OnUploadProgress = OnUploadProgress;
DownloadPlugin.OnComplete = fnDnStatus;
var sever = '192.168.137.1',
    port = 80,
    header = 'Header-name: Header value',
    body = '[[[FILE_BINARY]]]',
    filePath = '$USB_DIR/sda1/textfile.txt',
    uploadRatio = '10',
    serverType = 1;

DownloadPlugin.StartUpload(sever, port, header, body, filePath, uploadRatio, serverType);
```

I don't know meaning of `header` parameter. And I don't know how to specify url other than server root. Data was sent by POST request to `http://192.168.137.1:80/`.

At server side I saved it with simple script (`http://192.168.137.1:80/index.php`):

```
<?php
    $t = file_get_contents('php://input');
    if(strlen($t) > 1){
        echo 'some data arrived';
    }
    file_put_contents('input.txt', $t);
?>
```

Comment: Great! In which direcotry of the server the file will be uploaded? Can we replace the IP with an application url like "http://localhost/myapp/upload.php"?

Comment: File is not uploaded, file is sended as POST request to `http://IP:port/`, you need to save it yourself where you want it. I don`t know can you use FQN or not. Documentation does not specified it, and i did not tried it.

Comment: Does it send jpg files as well? Can I send a file from app directory. At the moment I do not have the device. Emulator only. Thanks

Comment: Emulator does not support DOWNLOAD plugin. you need to test it on actual device. I updated answer with script to save POST-data.

Answer (score -2):

I just uploaded a video file to my Samsung uhd, through smartthings. Hold-Click on video. Tap share. Send to device. When it's done you will see video just shared in upper right corner. Click on watch video. I'm watching it now but cant figure out where its stored on the tv